# RabbitMQ MessageConverter giving error when running Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to run a spring boot app (1.4.7.RELEASE) which will spit out message to a RabbitMQ queue. My build works successfully but when I am trying to run the app by `mvn clean spring-boot:run`, I am getting the following error in the file ProduceMessage.java

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Component
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring/rabbitmq-producer.xml")
public class ProduceMessage {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProduceMessage.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate myEventTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MessageConverter ctdMessageConverter;

    @Value("${fieldChangedEvent.MainQueue}")
    private String mainQ;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.ge.predix.dispatcherqproducer.api.produceFieldChangedEvent#
     * produceFieldChangedEvent(com.ge.dsp.pm.solution.service.fieldchanged.
     * FieldChangedEvent)
     */
    public boolean produceStringMessage(String data) {

        logger.debug("In produceStringMessage......");

        MessageProperties prop = new MessageProperties();
        prop.setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);

        Message msg = ctdMessageConverter.toMessage(data, prop);

        logger.debug("publishing string to ......= " + mainQ);
        myEventTemplate.convertAndSend(mainQ, msg);

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

The error :

> 2017-10-04 11:06:08.830[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m62162[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
>       [2m2017-10-04 11:06:08.849[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m62162[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>
> [2m2017-10-04 11:06:08.944[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m62162[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START ***************************
>        Description:
>        Field ctdMessageConverter in com.ge.power.tcs.producer.ProduceMessage required a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter' in your
>   configuration.

---

rabbitmq-producer.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd">
    <bean id="ctdMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter">
        <property name="delegates">
            <map>
                <entry key="text/plain" value-ref="simpleMessageConverter" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="simpleMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter" />          
 </beans>
```

Comment: And do you have a `@Bean` definition for the message converter you want injected here?

Comment: its of import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter; instance

Comment: My question is, what exactly were you expecting to be injected here, and why was that your expectation? It is not evident in the code you shared.

Comment: @sromit autoconfiguration doesnt provide a bean of MessageConverter type, if you are autowiring  then you have to create a bean of type MessageConverter as mentioned by edwin.

Comment: how do I create a bean of type MessageConverter?

Comment: I have added an xml to instantiate the bean..but still getting the same error..edited the code above

Comment: ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter makes more sense for listeners because the Message object has a contentType attribute (inside MessageProperties). For the senders, the RabbitTemplate class does not allow passing the content type. But if you are always passing the same content type then you can set the MessageConverter in the RabbitTemplate and it will set the content type for you. In the case of SimpleMessageConverter the content type will depend on the object type (byte array, text or serialized object).

Comment: If you have a single MessageConverter in your application context Spring Boot will automatically set it for you in the RabbitTemplate instance.

Comment: Given your method produceStringMessage, that always receives a String as data, you don't even need the ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter because SimpleMessageConverter uses CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN in case of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved once we mention `@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/rabbitmq-producer.xml")` in the main Application class in spring boot instead of `@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring/rabbitmq-producer.xml")` which contains the bean instantiation